# Grid lining up in one column

Tags: html, css, grid

i'm trying to create a grid template of 4X6, but they are all ending up in the same line, as if there is only one column.

I dont really no where else I can add detail about, if there are anymore questions i'll be glad to answear them.

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="div1">
            <img src="photos/00732ae4-9669-489c-b755-3dddc3dc0d56.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div3">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div4">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div5">
            <h1>hello world!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="div6">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div7">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div8">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div9">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div10">
            <h1> Trying again</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="div11">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div12">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div13"><img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div14">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div15"><img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div16">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
}

.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.div2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.div3 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.div4 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.div5 {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 5;
}

.div6 {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.div7 {
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.div8 {
    grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}

.div9 {
    grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 5;
}

.div10 {
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / 7 / 3;
}

.div11 {
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4;
}

.div12 {
    grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5;
}

.div13 {
    grid-area: 5 / 3 / 6 / 4;
}

.div14 {
    grid-area: 5 / 4 / 6 / 5;
}

.div15 {
    grid-area: 6 / 3 / 7 / 4;
}

.div16 {
    grid-area: 6 / 4 / 7 / 5;
}
```

The reason there are so many div is because there is a picture in each one.
iv'e tried using grid generator but that's the solution it gave me

Comment: Please share your codes as in [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So you want to have 4 columns and 6 rows? Is this the only problem?

Comment: yes that is the end goal, but everything is lining up in one column for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a runnable version of your code, it has 6 rows and 4 columns, could you explain what the problem is now?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
}

.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.div2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.div3 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.div4 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.div5 {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 5;
}

.div6 {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.div7 {
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.div8 {
    grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}

.div9 {
    grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 5;
}

.div10 {
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / 7 / 3;
}

.div11 {
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4;
}

.div12 {
    grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5;
}

.div13 {
    grid-area: 5 / 3 / 6 / 4;
}

.div14 {
    grid-area: 5 / 4 / 6 / 5;
}

.div15 {
    grid-area: 6 / 3 / 7 / 4;
}

.div16 {
    grid-area: 6 / 4 / 7 / 5;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="div1">
            <img src="photos/00732ae4-9669-489c-b755-3dddc3dc0d56.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div3">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div4">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div5">
            <h1>hello world!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="div6">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div7">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div8">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div9">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div10">
            <h1> Trying again</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="div11">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div12">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div13"><img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div14">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div15"><img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="div16">
            <img src="photos/00f96cae-b880-4883-8ae8-0c2bcb0888f0.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: its seems like there is still no actual grid, its just one column instead of 4, all lining up.

Comment: I added a picture of the layout, could you take a look? It has 4 columns and 6 rows

Comment: yes yours looks right, for some reason mine dosent work, i have tried 4 different browsers, but it dosent work in any of them.

Comment: https://imgur.com/tk7eAET this is what mine looks like

Comment: I think it's because you didn't correctly import the `CSS` file into your `HTML` file. Could you check that or share how you have done it?

Comment: That's so embarrassing, that was it, I guess it can happen to anybody..... So yeah, thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: Yes, don't worry, it happened to me a lot, that's why I could guess it. :)